# Geoserver: Time Slider for ImageMosaic Plugin for raster time-series data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geoserver

**Background:**

I am new to geoserver and the 'ImageMosaic Plugin for raster time-series data': I followed the tutorial on this [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) and managed to upload a raster time series to my local geoserver, which works pretty nice. I can access my single layers by changing the extension in the url like this:

```
&time=2009-10-01, &time=2009-11-01 and &time=2009-12-01
```

[image]

**Problem:**

What I want to do now, is to make a JS/jQuery time slider, that refreshes my page/map when the slider date value is changed by the user and in a way that the corresponding raster image is loaded.
Right now, I have three images in my series. To code a slider for those three raster files is not a problem. But if I will add another raster file to my time series in the future, I will need to also update my slider.
Is there any way to code the slider dynamically?

**In other words,** can I send some kind of request to my geoserver that returns the number of raster layers in my ImageMosaic and also their dates, so I can use this information when the slider is loaded and generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an administrator you can query the underlying index with a recent geoserver. See [this page](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/en/rest/index.html).

An alternative is to perse the GetCapabilities document and look for the TIME dimension values. You might want to fiddle with the Dimensions tab in GeoServer.

Comment: the link you provided is no working any more. Where could I find it? many thanks for your reply: it is very helpful!